# How many different arrangements of the word CABBAGES can be made with no two adjacent letters being the same?

Tags: combinatorics, permutations

The answer key states that it is 5760.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint:**

How many arrangements are there if you don't care?

Of these arrangements, how many are "bad" for the reason that the $A$'s were together?  How many were "bad" for the reason that the $B$'s were together?

> How many were "bad" for the reason that both the $A$'s were together *and* the $B$'s were together?

How many of the arrangements that we originally calculated are "good" then?

> Inclusion-exclusion and multinomial coefficients are your friend here.

Comment: So the possible ways for all arrangements is 8!/(2!2!) = 10080.  

The number of ways for AA but not BB is 5!*6C2 = 1800.  

The number of ways for BB but not AA is 5!*6C2 = 1800.  

The number of ways for both AA and BB is 5! = 120.  

By subtraction, I arrive at 6360. What did I do wrong here?

QUICK EDIT: I just realised that I can consider AA, consider BB, and add back the deficit of AA union BB

Comment: Okay it's all good, I got the answer via the hints :)